# cucumber result not shown on test explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow

I am following the specflow getting started, http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/

I am stuck at the step 6 Run your test – it is not green yet.

The test result does not shown any result on my Visual Studio Test Explorer.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2013.

Comment: Have you installed the [Specflow VS extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee)?

Comment: Which test runner is SpecFlow configured to use? By default it uses NUnit, not MSTest.